# Google Ads API failing

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am working with Google Ads and taking look in the documentation to see how to code a campaign.

```
from google.ads.google_ads.client import GoogleAdsClient

def create_campaign(google_ads_client, campaign_name, budget_micros):
    campaign_operation = google_ads_client.service.campaign.create(
        customer_id="YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID",
        campaign={
            "name": campaign_name,
            "advertising_channel_type": "SEARCH",
            "status": "PAUSED",
            "manual_cpc": {
                "enhanced_cpc_enabled": True
            },
            "campaign_budget": {
                "amount_micros": budget_micros
            },
            "network_settings": {
                "target_google_search": True,
                "target_search_network": True,
                "target_content_network": False,
                "target_partner_search_network": False
            }
        }
    )

    # Execute the campaign operation
    response = campaign_operation.execute()

    # Print the created campaign's resource name
    print("Created campaign with resource name: " + response.resource_name)

# Set up the Google Ads API client
google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage()

# Define the campaign details
campaign_name = "My Campaign"
budget_micros = 5.000000
```

The error raised with macro budget and I don't know what is this, I tried set the number based on what documentation suggesting and still don't understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/campaign_budget#:%7E:text=amount_micros,-Field%20description&text=The%20amount%20of%20the%20budget,at%2030.4%20times%20this%20amount.) it says:

> The amount of the budget, in the local currency for the account. Amount is specified in micros, where one million is equivalent to one currency unit. Monthly spend is capped at 30.4 times this amount.

so this means how much you will spend on your Ad/campaign.
Why did you add a point in the `budget_micros` variable? I assume it must be `budget_micros = 5000000` ?